# MySQL connectivity error

Tags: mysql, configuration, connectivity

I have a MySQL database on a Linux server that I am able to access through putty logging into servers terminal. When I try to connect to the MySQL database remotely, I get the error:

> *Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet, system error: 0*

I have added `bind-address:127.0.0.1` in `my.cnf` file and port 3306 is already opened. What other configurations do I need to change to be able to connect to MySQL remotely?

I am using Navicat / HeidiSQL + SSH to connect remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Your `bind-address` needs to be `0.0.0.0` or at the very least the IP address of the interface you will be connecting to from your remote machine.

If you set it to `127.0.0.1` only loopback connections from the server can be made.

Comment: ok,does 0.0.0.0 enable connectivity from all remote machines.
apart from this any other configuration changes i need to make??